# How can I prevent water from entering my ears during a bath?

Tags: personal-care, safety

I am a young girl but still facing difficulty when taking a bath, because during the bath a little amount of water usually enters my ears and disturbs me. After bathing I am feel something strange like a burden in my ears. Sometimes I hear a strange voice from inner side of ears. I am really worry about this problem. How can I get rid of this situation during baths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ear pieces specially made for swimming, which will keep the water out of your ears even when your head comes completely under water.
Normal ear plugs, like people use in noisy work or for traveling will work as will wax plugs which you shape to the inside of your ears.

But you can get used to that feeling, I used to get upset with water in my ears when swimming but am not bothered anymore after many regular swimming session. It just went away over the months.

Answer (score -1):

- Shake or drain water from your ears. Just tilt your head and let gravity do its thing. ...
- Dry your ears. Use a clean towel to gently rub the outside of your ear. ...
- Use ear drops. You can buy over-the-counter ear drops that will help dry up any leftover water.

To keep water out of your ear when showering and bathing, place half of a cotton ball rolled in 1 tablespoon of petroleum jelly. The cotton ball should be saturated with jelly and not have any dry exposed areas. Place this over the bowl of the outer ear. Do not shove the cotton ball into the ear canal.

**Keep your ears clean and dry, especially after swimming.** Thoroughly dry each ear canal after swimming or bathing.

You may have to take some medicine to help get rid of the infection. Stay away from water until the infection has gone. You still have to keep clean though, so you can wear a shower cap or ear plugs to stop water getting into your ears in the shower or bath.

1. Always maintain proper ear wax hygiene.
2. Wear ear plugs while swimming.
3. Always take good care of your skin.
4. Consider using ear drops.